# Unity3d Sqlite , Can i show output "The data is empty" if the data table is empty?

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I am was create application in unity. But i want to show output "the data is empty" if the data in table is empty. Can you fix it ?

```
   void Update(){
    //Clear output Text Field
    output.text = "";

    var sql = "SELECT * FROM t_informasi;";


    using (var cmd = dbCon.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
            while(reader.Read()){
                output.text = output.text + reader.GetInt32(0).ToString()+". " + reader.GetString(1) + "\n" + reader.GetString(2)+"\n\n";
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class when constructing strings. Look at the class, your string creation could probably be better broken down to use the class better. Such as with the [AppendLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb3sbadh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var cmd = dbCon.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
            while(reader.Read())
                sb.Append(reader.GetInt32(0).ToString()+". " + reader.GetString(1) + "\n" + reader.GetString(2)+"\n\n");
        } 
}


if(sb.Length <= 0)
  sb.Append("the data is empty");

output.text = sb.ToString();
```

Though I can't imagine you want this code in an `Update` method. Your database will be accessed every frame.